# Is there a reason why I can't get .upper() to work? Keeps giving something called AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

def wordlist():
    wordlistfile=open("dictionary.txt","r")
    word_list=[]
    for line in wordlistfile:
        strip_line=line.strip("\n").lower()
        word_list.append(strip_line)
    return (word_list)

#I want to change the .lower() here to .upper() but it keeps breaking as soon as
#change it and have to keep changing it back. This function opens the word list
#file and converts into a comma seperated list.

def randomword(words_list):
    word = random.randint(0, len(words_list)-1)
    return words_list[word]

#This function picks a random integer in the range of the word list and uses that
#integer to call an indexed word

def hangingman (hangmanpictures, wrongletters, rightletters, random_word):
    print(hangmanpictures[len(wrongletters)])
    blanks = "_" * len(random_word)

    for i in range(len(random_word)):
        if random_word[i] in rightletters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + random_word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end=" ")
    print("\nWrong letters: ", end=" ")
    print()
    for letter in wrongletters:
        print(letter, end=" ")

#function that runs the game

def guesses (guessed):
     while True:
        guess = input("\nGuess a letter: ")
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("Please enter one letter at a time")
        elif guess in guessed:
            print("You have already tried that letter, please try again")
        elif guess not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm":
            print("Please enter an ENGLISH letter")
        else:
            return guess

#function that checks whether or not if a guess is a valid guess or not
#I was trying to change the guess into .upper() as well to match the character
#from the word that is randomly chosen from above, but something kept breaking
#and I had to change it back

def again():
    choice = input("Do you want to play again? (Y or N): ").upper()
    return choice
#wanna play again? 

hangmanpictures = ['''
   +----+
   |    |
        |
        |
        |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
        |
        |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
   |    |
        |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
  /|    |
        |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
  /|\   |
        |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
  /|\   |
  /     |
        |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
   O    |
  /|\   |
  / \   |
        |
=========''']

print("Welcome to HANGMAN")
word_list = wordlist()
random_word = randomword(word_list)

wrongletters = ""
rightletters = ""
finishedgame = False
guessed = rightletters+wrongletters

print(random_word)


while True:
    hangingman (hangmanpictures, wrongletters, rightletters, random_word)
    playerguess = guesses(wrongletters + rightletters)
    if playerguess in random_word:
        rightletters = rightletters + playerguess
        correctletters=True
        for i in range(len(random_word)):
            if random_word[i] not in rightletters:
                correctletters=False
                break
        if correctletters:
            print("You have found the correct word, congratulations!!! The hidden word was: \n {}".format(random_word))
            finishedgame=True
    else:
        wrongletters = wrongletters + playerguess
        if len(wrongletters) == len(hangmanpictures)-1:
            hangingman (hangmanpictures, wrongletters, rightletters, random_word)
            print("\nYou have lost. The word was: {}".format(random_word))
            finishedgame=True

    if finishedgame:
        if again()=="Y":
            wrongletters = ""
            rightletters = ""
            finishedgame = False
            random_word = randomword(word_list)
        else:
            print("Press enter to quit the game.")
            input()
            break
```

What I tried to do after fixing the previous problem was to capitalize all the words and user input using .upper(), but Python Shell kept giving me something called an AttributeError about for .upper or something like that.

What I had tried was in def wordlist() function, I put strip_line=line.strip("\n").upper() and in the def guesses(guessed) function i put guess = guess.upper() and it kept breaking. However when I changed those back to how it is with .lower() it works perfectly fine. But for the sake of aesthetics I want it to be capital letters, as I think it would look better with capital letters rather than lowercase letters.

For those that care, the previous error I was having with this code is that I didn't put in the .lower() in the def wordlist() function.

Comment: You need to take the time to read [mcve]. Specifically the minimal part.

Comment: Besides, MCVE, I recommend [basic debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  You don't seem to have any idea where your program is going wrong.  Also, I strongly recommend incremental programming: write a few lines, debug the addition, and *then* continue.  Here, you have about 150 lines of code to search for problems.

Comment: I narrowed it down to two spots which are noted in the program where the error may be occuring, but I don't know how to fix it, and I'm asking for help. I'm sorry I'm not a professional coder.

Comment: *I think that there may be something incomplete within this function but can't figure out what is going wrong with it. The problem is within this function or the actual program down below.* - is one of the comments. It is better to say what was expected from the function and what is happening right now.

Comment: I get a different output: a letter that appears within the word is *not* added to the wrong letters list, but the display of the word so far is cut off at a single correct letter.  The hanging man accrues new pieces at the right spots.

Comment: I have yet to get program to identify even a single correct letter. I ran the program right as is, the secret word picked by the computer was "wax" so i entered in w and it put w into the wrong letters list and put the 1st hanging man piece into the picture indicating a wrong answer.

Comment: I installed Python 3.5.2 and ran your currently given code (which includes the change I found above).  It works as expected.  You'll have to give more detail on what's causing the problem if you require more help.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I have a little under one month of experience in any computer language and I don't know what is causing the problem in this code to make it run the way it is, instead of running the way I want it to. @Prune

Comment: Understood; we're trying to focus on what's needed to resolve the problem, and to help train you to find more problems without taking your time to consult with us.  What version of Python do you have?  What OS?  What interface do you use to run it?

Comment: Most of all, we need the detailed debugging information.  At least put the print statements suggested around that letter-matching **if**, run it, and post both the code and the output.  Generic declarations of what you did and what result you got are simply not enough to handle this problem.

Comment: I found the problem and corrected it, thanks for all the help! its working perfectly now, now just to add in exception handling for some minor parts of the code to cover all the possible user inputs. Is there a way that I can close this question?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the loop that fills **blanks** in **hangingman**:

```
            blanks = blanks[:1] + random_word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

You're chopping off all but the first character of the string.  It should be

```
            blanks = blanks[:i] + random_word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

Note **i** in place of **1**.

I made a few minor edits to make this run in Python2.7 as well as Python 3, and it now works for me.  The above is the only logic change.

---

For your future use, all I did was to run the program, see where the output appeared strange, and then stuck in a **print** statement to track the values.  If you have a sick patient, ask where it hurts.

```
for i in range(len(random_word)):
    if random_word[i] in rightletters:
        blanks = blanks[:i] + random_word[i] + blanks[i+1:]
        print "DEBUG", i, blanks
```

Comment: Ah thanks for that, I didn't notice that little typo since i's and 1s look very similar on the screen in python, I fixed that little piece and ran the code again, but I'm still unable to get any kind of correct letters with every input being automatically put into wrong letters

Comment: I tried adding in print statements and input statements everywhere to try to figure out whats going on but i can't find the source of the issue I'm still having where it wont register a correct letter at all.

Comment: I don't see the code and output from that effort.  Your print statements just before and after **if playerguess in random_word:** *should* show the problem easily enough.

Comment: i didnt update the code on here with them, because it would take well over an hour doing it on here. It took me an hour to get all the spacing correct when writing this  post initially.

Comment: Edit the question: copy the code from your text editor and paste into the edit box.  Select the entire body of new code.  Click on the "code sample" icon, **{}**.  That should take care of formatting the code.